# Spring SFTP connection - get file from SFTP server

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

I am new to spring. I am using spring to get files from remote server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-2.2.xsd">

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="xxxxxxxx" />
    <property name="user" value="wildfly" />
    <property name="password" value="w!ldfly" />
    <property name="port" value="22" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel" />

<sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="triggerFtpInBound" auto-create-local-directory="true"
    local-directory="/tmp/test" filename-pattern="*" channel="sftpChannel"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" remote-directory="/home/wildfly" delete-remote-files="true">
    <int:poller cron="1/10 * * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am using the following code.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/spring-sftp.xml");
```

I am not getting any errors when i run it but i am not getting any files copied either. Please let me know the mistakes in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "KnownHosts" property solved my issue. I am getting files transferred now.

```
<property name="knownHosts" value = "C:\knownhosts"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to debug just looking at static configuration.

The first step is to turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` and see what's happening.

If you can't figure it out from the logs, post them; if too big for here, use a github gist, pastebin, or similar.

Spring Integration uses jsch under the covers; you can enable its logging as described [in the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-jsch-logging).